# Error:(30, 16) error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView

Tags: android

i get this error when i try to run my app

```
> `Error:(30, 16) error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView`
Error:(68, 24) error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView
Error:(100, 33) error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

every time i try to run it i get this errors 
that is my gradle file  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jungleadventureninja.game"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}

`
```

Im new in android studio .. can any one help me .. TX
note : this app is an eclipse app .. but i did open it in AS because its much better

Comment: Use `setContentView()` instead of `SetContentView()` in your Activity class

Comment: whats the different between them ?

Comment: Camel humps `setContentView()` starts with lower case `s`.

Comment: how can i find the activity class please ... I new  in android studio ..

Comment: Then you should refer some Android Studio tutorials.

Comment: Please learn some Java, first. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: im not developing an app .. im just reskin  it ..

Comment: The same applies. Try to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set view you need to use `setContentView()` method of Activity instead of `SetContentView` which compiler interprets as nonexistent class.

Comment: can you tall me exactly how to do it please .. im new in  AS and i don't know how to do that .. tx

Comment: in your MainActivity(I assume you use default name) you've got onCreate() method, right inside that method use `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file)`